# Weighted $\ell^2$ space is Hilbert

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

This is my exam's question that I could not solve it. Please help me to undrestand how to solve it:
let $\{w_n\}$  is a  positive real numbers sequence, and let
$$\ell^2(w):=\left\{\{x_n\}:x_n \in R ,\sum_{n=1}^\infty w_n |x_n|^2< \infty\right\}.$$
1) I needed to show that $\ell^2(w)$ is a Hilbert space under inner product
$$ \langle x,y\rangle:= \sum_{n=1}^\infty w_n x_n y_n$$ for all $ x=\{x_n\}\in \ell^2(w),y=\{y_n\}\in \ell^2(w)$

2) I needed to find a positive linear functional
$$f\colon\ell^2(w)\rightarrow R$$ and find it's norm.

Thanks.

Comment: For the first question, do you know what you have to check?

Comment: yes,I need to show that the  defined inner product is well define and is real an inner product, then I should show every couchy sequence is converge, but how to do it,I really do not know

Answer (score 0):

1) Well-definiteness of the inner product is given by classical Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. Bilinearity should not be problematic, and positive definiteness uses the fact that the terms of $w$ are positive.

Now it remains to prove completeness. This can be done similarly as the case $w_n=1$ for each $n$.